# Access localStorage set by Safari from native app using UIWebView

Tags: xcode, html, uiwebview, local-storage

Is it possible to read localStorage contents for yourdomain.com using UIWebView, if the localStorage was written by Safari 4?

Assuming on iPhone 3.x >, Android >

Answer (score 0):

localStorage is available from any domain. It's stored in a database that resides on the device. You can see what's in localStorage from your console using web dev tools. You can access it using JS as well.

```
var key = 'foo';
localStorage.getItem(key);
```

Answer (score 0):

On iOS, localStorage appears to be separate for each app.
Doing a quick test on the iOS simulator (with iOS 7.1), it looks like it keeps localStorage for each site as a sqlite database in your app's Library/Caches folder.

Your app doesn't have access to Safari's sandbox, so it wouldn't have access to Safari's localStorage.